# PHP Session ending automatically

Tags: php, session, authentication

I do a lot of work using PHP frameworks but I am now building a simple login system from scratch and I am stumped. I am using PDO for my database queries. I have a simple login form which points to the same page using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. Then I have this code...

```
<?php
//LOG IN
if($_POST['login_submit']){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  //Query
  $database->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
  $database->bind(':username',$username);
  $database->bind(':password',$password);
  $rows = $database->resultset();
  $count = count($rows);
  if($count > 0){
    session_start();
    //Assign session variables
    $_SESSION['username']   = $username;
    $_SESSION['password']   = $password;
    $_SESSION['logged_in']  = 1;
} else {
   $login_msg[] = 'Sorry, that login does not work';
}
}
```

When I login, its fine. It starts the session. But as soon as I go to another page the session is broken. I suspect maybe cause the session_start() is in the if($_POST['login_submit']) condition. But I could sware Ive done it like this before. Any help would be awesome..thanks!

Comment: Why you want to have `session_start()` inside a condition?

Comment: The problem might be with the other page that appears broken. It sounds like you are not starting the session on every page.

Comment: `session_start();` needs to be at the top (most of the time) of ALL files used. Not using will break your code.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your code...

```
if($_POST['login_submit']){
```

Only, if you submit your login form, the session is started.

And, on all other pages, you have to call session_start() ...